# program using Scheme that evaluates a postfix expression

Tags: scheme, postfix-notation

I want to convert a postfix expression using **scheme** 
The expression will be given to the interpreter as a list of operands and operators such as **display( postfix(30 8 7 + / 3 4 - *) )** 
This example should return -2 as answer.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a homework service. SO expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: Its not for homework i tried solving it multiple time sir, i just need some help.

Comment: If you tried solving it multiple times, show what you tried. Then we can point out where you went wrong and how to fix it. But we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: i'm sorry sir it is but i tried a lot,i dont want a bad grade either can you please help me.

Comment: You need to implement a stack for the operands. Loop over the list. When you get a value, push it onto the stack. When you get an operator, pop the operands off the stack, call the corresponding function, and push the result onto the stack.

Comment: Bad grade? I thought it wasn't homework.

Comment: Thanku sir, i wish someone provided me a pseudo code or something i'm new to programming i want to be like u someday.

Comment: At the end, display the top element of the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's pseudo-code:

- Initialize stack to empty list
- For each element e in the expression:

  - if e is a number, push it onto the stack
  - otherwise, call the function corresponding to the operator (you can use an association list or `cond` to find this), passing the stack as the parameter
        - The function pops the needed arguments off the stack
        - It calculates the result
        - It pushes the result onto the stack
        - It returns the updated stack, which the main loop assigns back to the stack variable
- At the end, print the top element of the stack